# How to crop an image in Octave?

Tags: image, image-processing, octave

Is there a built-in function in Octave to crop a specific region from an image? I have installed the image processing package but I don't find a function like `imcrop` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if your image (which is a matrix in Octave) is `I`, and you want to crop from `x,y` a block of size `w,l`, then `resize(circshift(I,-x,-y), w, l)` ought to do it. Basically, shift the matrix so that `x,y` is now at `1,1`, and just cut off the rest of the matrix past `w,l`.

EDIT: Actually, that was before I learned about matrix indexing. Instead, this is what you want:

`Croppedimage = Image(y:y+l-1, x:x+w-1)`

Comment: `Croppedimage = Image(y:y+l-1, x:x+w-1)` used to work, but for some reason not anymore, at least not for color images. It somehow turns them gray scale.

Answer (score 2):

The `imcrop` function exists now:

```
imcrop(Image, [x y 20 20])
```

would crop an image of `20x20` pixels starting from the `(x,y)` coordinate.